# How to use Facebook appAccessToken with Spring Social

Tags: java, facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I'm a bit confused as to how to use Facebook's app access token with Spring Social.

I already have an app access token by making a GET request to:

http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

I can't use (for reasons I don't want to discuss here) the standard Spring Social connection creation flow and I want to use this token (if possible).

My question is generally directed toward the `GraphApi`.

So in general can I use an app access token acquired via a standard GET to make requests to the Graph Api through Spring Social ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are very few things that the app access token can be used for. Most of the operations in the Graph API are for fetching user data and therefore you *MUST* obtain a user access token. The app access token you have will not work.

If you're planning to use your app access token to fetch a user's profile, see their friends list, or post to their timeline (or anything that pertains to a user), then you're out of luck. Imagine the chaos that would ensue if all you had to do to read and post on behalf of a user is obtain an app access token! You *must* get the user's permission for that kind of thing.

There are 3 ways to get a user access token: Authorization code grant (which is what Spring Social's ConnectController does and is most appropriate for traditional web applications), implicit grant (which is more appropriate for client-side Javascript), and resource owner credentials grant (which is most appropriate for mobile or desktop applications where doing a browser redirect is awkward, difficult, or impossible).

The app access token you have is only intended to consume API endpoints that are application-centric and do not pertain to any given user. There are a few such operations in Facebook's API, but the only one that immediately comes to mind is that you can use an app token to create test users (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/).

Just as most of Facebook's API is user-centric, likewise is Spring Social's Facebook API binding. If, however, there's an app-centric operation that you'd like to see added to Spring Social, I'd appreciate it if you'd let me know at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SOCIALFB.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer. I have another quick question. What if the user has already given my app permissions. Can I then use the app access token for full account access ? Thanks again.

Comment: No. The app access token is *only* for app-related functions. It doesn't matter what permissions a user may have granted. You must use the user token for user-centric operations.

Comment: what about Facebook Notifications API?

Comment: Hi Craig - I have a few examples of how the app token could be used effectively but thought it better to start a new question and not hijack so here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277094/use-app-access-token-with-spring-social-facebook-to-query-public-pages